# How to ping a java and bedrock Minecraft server's information with Python

Tags: python, minecraft

I'm trying to find a way to ping a Java+Bedrock Minecraft server using python but I couldn't find the right import to use.
I have recently used `mcstatus` to get the information but now for some reason I don't get a response from the server anymore.
I also tried using `mcipc` but I also couldn't get a response from the server.

Does anybody know of a way to ping a java+bedrock server? (there is a chance I used mcipc wrong, but about mcstatus it worked before the server added the bedrock compatibility plugin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Java, you do it like this:

```
serverdata = 'mc.hypixel.net' #you can add port in like this: mc.hypixel.net/25565 
data = requests.get(f"https://api.minetools.eu/ping/{serverdata}").json()
try:
    print(f"Server is up, and there are {data['players']['online']} players.")
except:  
    print("Server is offline.")
```

For Bedrock, I have no idea. Sorry about that.

Comment: Is request apart of a library I assume? because it doesn't recognize that object

Comment: The requests library gets information from sites, making it useful for getting info from APIs. So yes, it's a library.